# do you need to remove mean and divide by std for testing normality?

Tags: normalization, normality-assumption

I am running a `kstest` on MATLAB. When I take the data directly,  i.e. `kstest(data)`, the result says that my data is non normal. However, if I use `kstest((data-mean(data))/std(data))` it would come out as normal distribution.

What is the correct way of testing normality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you subtract the mean and divide by standard deviation then you can no longer use that particular test. We discussed this several time here. The reason is that `kstest` function in MATLAB is for a *known* distribution, meaning that you know its mean and variance. You're *estimating* them from sample, which makes this test invalid as implemented in MATLAB. Look up [Lilliefors test](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html) for your purpose. Other software packages such as SPSS may have implemented it in the their KS test functions, check the docs.

Comment: ... or Shapiro-Wilk's.

Comment: This is correct, though when someone asks about a stats package that package may call Lilliefors test "Kolmogorov-Smirnov" (like SPSS does).

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks, I clarified my answer. In fact when I ran into this issue with MATLAB, I assumed that they'd take care of unknown parameters case. It's great that SPSS does this

Comment: If SPSS is a problem because it is costly, you could try the gnu version: PSPP; https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/html_node/KOLMOGOROV_002dSMIRNOV.html#KOLMOGOROV_002dSMIRNOV

Comment: much thanks for the explanation, great for me who's knows very fundamental of statistic

Answer (score 1):

<s>By subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, you're making your data normal.</s> If you want to *test* for normality, I would say the most intuitive way would be to plot a histogram and see how close it is to a normal distribution. For a more analytical approach, you can always run a [Shapiro-Wilk test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test).

Comment: You might reasonably say you make normal data *standard* normal by subtracting the mean & dividing by the standard deviation.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should have been more clear. However, I think it's still fair to say that doing so would still be making your data normal. The standard normal distribution is still a normal distribution after all :)

Comment: Why would you want to say you make normal data normal? Anyway, what your first sentence appears to be saying is that you make non-normal data normal by subtracting the mean & dividing by the standard deviation!

Comment: If the original data are not normal, then subtracting the mean and dividing by the SD will *not* make it normal. Conversely, if the data were normal to begin with, then scaling them will not make it "more" normal. I fail to see what you are trying to say. Shapiro-Wilk is a very good point.